# Getting complete educations from LinkedIn API (working partially)

Tags: linkedin-api

I have two LinkedIn profiles, one "real" and another used for testing.
Using the API console (https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) I tested retrieving "educations", but strangely on the real profile I cant't retrieve anything but an id and start/end dates, while on the test profile I can retrieve all details about education.
I have the necessity to use the REST API and not JS or other methods.
Anyway, is there anything I can check to retrieve all education details about my real profile? Am I missing something?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you authenticated your API account against your "test" profile.

The `/v1/people/~:(....)` API will return all the complete data for the account the API was used to authenticate. But for "connections", 1st degree and beyond, the API will only retrieve data as if it were a 3rd degree connection.

Using the API as `/v1/people/id=...` or `/v1/people/url=...` results in "3rd degree" type access data.

[From the profile-api](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api)

> Requesting by member token only returns a profile from the logged in person's three degree network and doesn't return any out-of-network profiles. You cannot use a member token to get a public profile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I authenticate the two profile in the same manner, using the /v1/people/~:(....) API
Can it be something related to the profile itself ?
Moreover I noticed that if I select a choose an Institute (or a degree or a  course) from the list it is showed in the resulting json, but if I write an Institute that is not in the list it is not showed up....